# Mock Method2 of Interface called in another method1

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking, testify

I am writing unit tests for `Method1()`

I want to mock `Method2()` that is called from `Method1()` of the same interface.

We can mock methods of another interface easily by taking that mocked implementation in the struct. But I'm not sure how to mock a method of the same interface.

```
type ISample interface {
    Method1()
    Method2()
}

type Sample struct {
    
}

func (s Sample) Method1() {
    s.Method2()
}

func (s Sample) Method2() {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by using an embedded interface.

```
type ISample interface {
    Method1()
    Method2()
}

type Sample struct {
    ISample
}

func (s Sample) Method1() {
    s.ISample.Method2()
}

func (s Sample) Method2() {
    
}
```

While creating an object of Sample, assign mocked ISample to `ISample`.